# Unable to connect to Storage Account via Container, Error: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, azure-blob-storage, docker-container, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable Function in **Python** which I wanted to Containerize. I have used the following Image in the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

ENV AzureWebJobsStorage="<connection-string>"

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

I am getting the following Error in Container Logs:

```
---> DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.DurableTaskStorageException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
```

the underlying OS details for the above image is as follows:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I believe I already have `ca-certificates` installed on this system:

```
$ apt-get install ca-certificates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I however have the `Allow Blob public access` part disabled in Storage Account Settings > Configuration, because of Business requirement:

[Storage Account Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTcyp.png)

I believe that since Azure Durable Functions have some Operation related folder automatically created as a Container in Azure Storage Account, I have somehow denied access due the fact that the SSL Certificate is not a valid one in the Image. Any alternate solution how to connect with Storage Account via Docker Container?

Tried ways upgrade this Certificate, but didn't help much!